How can I do an aggregate function with multiple columns with a Google Sheets query?
In Google Sheets I have numbers in both columns of A2:B11.
I'd like to get the combined average of the numbers from  both columns using the QUERY function.
The result would be a single  number that represents the average of all the values from Columns A and B combined.
I tried the following formula but it doesn't work:
=query(A1:B11, "select avg(A&B)", 1)  

I can perform the calculation with the AVERAGE function, but my application is significantly more complex than that and I would prefer averaging across columns within QUERY's "Select" statement.
Does anyone have a solution?

Average by Column

try like this:

=QUERY(A1:B11, "select avg(A),avg(B)", 1)

to kill labels you can do:

=QUERY(A1:B11, "select avg(A),avg(B) label avg(A)'',avg(B)''", 1)
Combined Average

to get average of two columns:

=AVERAGE(A1:B)


to include QUERY

=AVERAGE(QUERY(A:B, "select * where B is not null", 0))

QUERY without AVERAGE

=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A1:B11, "select avg(A),avg(B) label avg(A)'',avg(B)''", 0)),"select avg(Col1) label avg(Col1)''", 0)
